# Is there a way to programmatically add attributes to the Glass Mapper Link class

Tags: glass-mapper

In my code, if the Link field target Item matches the context item I want to add CSS class as active and also add the attribute ***aria-current=page***.

Is there a way to `add custom attributes to the Glass Mapper Link`?

```
 foreach (var languageResource in languageResourcesList.Children)
      {
        var languageResourceItem = new MvcContext().SitecoreService.GetItem<LanguageResources>(languageResource.Id);
        Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link linkField = languageResourceItem.LanguagePageLink;
        if (linkField != null)
        {
          var targetItemId = linkField.TargetId;
          if (targetItemId == Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToGuid())
          {
            linkField.Class = "active";
           // add attribute aria-current=page to the Link field
          }
        }
        languageResources.Add(languageResourceItem);
      }
```

**Cshtml:**

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(@languageResource, y => y.LanguagePageLink, isEditable: true))
                {
                    <span class="label">@languageResource.LanguageLabel</span>
                    <span class="lang" lang="@languageResource.LangaugeCode">@languageResource.NativeLanguageLabel</span>
                }
```

**Expected output:**

```
<a href="/xx/xx/xxx" aria-current="page" class="active">
  <span class="label">Chinese</span><span class="lang" lang="ch">中文</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you can `add Custom Attribute to the Glass Mapper link` as below:

***new { @class = "active", @aria-current = "page"}***

```
@using (Html.Glass().BeginRenderLink(@languageResource, y => y.LanguagePageLink, new { @class = "active", @aria-current = "page"}, isEditable: true))
            {
                <span class="label">@languageResource.LanguageLabel</span>
                <span class="lang" lang="@languageResource.LangaugeCode">@languageResource.NativeLanguageLabel</span>
            }
```

You can apply conditions-based classes as well, for active or not.

Comment: I want to do it in the code (repository) at the field level. I am trying to avoid writing the logic on the cshtml

if (targetItemId == Sitecore.Context.Item.ID.ToGuid())
          {
            linkField.Class = "active";
           // add attribute aria-current=page to the Link field
          }